# Is IF(integer) valid in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working through updating this PHP based website and I've noticed that there are a lot of these statements like

```
IF(foo['bar']){
    //Foo your Bars here
}
```

For this rudimentary example, my analysis indicated that the value stored at `foo['bar']` is an integer.

I distinctly remember learning in school that `value != 0` translates to TRUE when performing a boolean test - does this hold true in PHP as well?

Comment: Did you test it? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ca18f1fbe57194b8056e77cd930bac7c64dc5d0

Comment: @AbraCadaver I did not. I was not aware that site exists. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You could test it on your website.  Also check http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for the info. I tested and it turns out that VALUE != 0 is what always translates to true any non zero value is true, even in PHP. That's pretty nifty. Thanks.